# Rails simple_form server side validations lost URL params

Tags: simple-form

I'm using simple_form for a form and passing in some URL parameters
to prepopulate the form.

This code works OK

```
<%= f.input :first_name, :label => 'First Name', :input_html => { :value => params['first'] } %>
```

Using the URL

```
http://localhost:3000/charities/new?first=Bob
```

Which outputs this HTML

```
<input class="string required" id="charity_first_name" name="charity[first_name]" size="50" type="text" value="Bob" />
```

However if the form server side validation fails the page reloads but the prepopulate
value is gone? This is the rendered HTML

```
<input class="string required" id="charity_first_name" name="charity[first_name]" size="50" type="text" />
```

Can anyone help advise how to prepopulate simple_form and retain those
values if the serverside validastion fails and the page reloads?

Thank you.

Comment: Related for `form_tag`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129229/rails-restoring-contents-of-non-model-form-that-uses-form-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to make it works with validations you should preset object values in controller like this:

```
@charity = Charity.new
@charity.first_name = params[:first]
```

Comment: Great! Many thanks Nash, works perfect for simple_form value populating both before initial submit and after any failed serverside validations.