# Rails 4: Create parent only if nested model is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Well, not a good title but here is the problem.

[Question updated]

I have two models, Word and Definition. When the user looks up a word the definitions are enlisted and there should be a form below the definitions so that the user can contribute by adding up another definition. So far no problem. But if the search returns no result, I will ask the user to create Word along with its first definition.

I do not know how to deal with the form and logic of the problem. It is more than a nested form. Because something like `form_for [@word, @word.definitions.build] do |form|` would not work since there is no @word object to which the/a new definition can be referred.

Addendum:
I seem to find a way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911017/3606431). It just works but not so clean to me. If you think there is a better solution please share it anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you need a nested from, there's a Railscast on this http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: make the form for the dictionary item so that the entries are nested and then in the controller use find_or_create...

Comment: it would help a lot if you posted the two relevant models, the relevant view and the controller

Comment: it's hard to speculate on what "a better solution" might be without specifics like the models...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to implement a form object ([RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects)). I'd use a transaction so I'm not left with any orphan database records.

In the submit method of your form object:

```
def submit
  if dictionary_item.present?
    # just save the entry
  else
    # start a transaction so both operations will either succeed or fail
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      # save the new dictionary_item
      # save the entry
    end
  end
  # return true if the objects are valid and persisted, false otherwise
end
```

Make sure to call `save!` or `create!` inside the transaction. The bangs are important, because an error has to be raised for the transaction to trigger a rollback.

Comment: I guess this is almost what I need. In this case, how am I supposed to retrieve dictionary_item from the view? Via a hidden field?

Comment: I combined this with Form Helpers as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1911017/3606431 Tx.